# Select tag collapsing after hiding all options

Tags: javascript, html

Problem are well described in header. When i using .hide() to all option tags in select tag, after hiding last element it collapse.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dXVCn/

also, code from fiddle:

```
<select size="4">
<option>Test 1</option>
<option>Test 2</option>
</select>

$(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        $('select option:selected').hide();
    })
})
```

Comment: Whicn browser did you test. I don't think hiding an option is supported cross browser wise. Otherwise just give a min width to the select.

Comment: to support cross browser(IE) it is better to remove the option instead of hiding it.... Giving a width to the select could solve the collapsing issue

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MGQhE/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a `min-width/width` for your select, and i don't think you can just hide them, instead remove them. and before removal if you want to preserve the options for latter use, you can store in some cache like data cache of jquery.

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('select');
    $select.data('myOptions', $select.find('option')); //save it here in case needed later

    $('button').on('click',function(){
        $select.find(':selected').remove();
    });
    //sample mathod to show populating them back
    $('#getBack').on('click', function(){
        $select.html($select.data('myOptions'));
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
select{
    min-width:60px;
    /*play around with fixed width/max-width to make sure your select is in proper shape.*/
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3X2qV/)**

Comment: @PSL My dumpness it wont make sense.+1

Comment: @captain No problem... That's why i wondered.. :) You made me think twice though.. :)